# Was Brad Pitt's '50 feet of crap' line in Moneyball a reference to Jennifer Aniston's in Friends?

Tags: dialogue, friends, moneyball

In Friends S02E01 (from 1995), Rachel is sad because Ross has a new girlfriend, as she is discussing with Joey:

> Joey: How're you doing?
>
> Rachel: I'm okay.
>
> Joey: Ooh, that bad, huh?
>
> Rachel: What?
>
> Joey: Look, I can sense when women are depressed and vulnerable. It's
>   one of my gifts.
>
> Rachel: When I saw him get off that plane with her, I really thought I
>   hit rock bottom. But today, it's like there's rock bottom, 50 feet of
>   crap, then me.

Here Rachel uses the iconic '50 feet of crap' line.

Then in the 2011 movie Moneyball starring Brad Pitt, Billy (Brad Pitt) mentions:

> BILLY:
>              Okay, stop. The problem we're trying to
>              solve is that this is an unfair game.
>              There are rich teams, poor teams, 50 feet
>              of crap and then there's us.

Was it purely coincidental for the movie writer to write the same line to be used by Jennifer's ex-husband, or was it an intentional reference to the Friends episode?

If it indeed was a reference, was Brad Pitt aware of the connection of this dialogue with his ex-wife?

Comment: isn't if *50 feet of crap* is that much iconic as you say, it'd be a general cuss-word? Also waiting 1995 to 2011 to just say one line in connection to that, i don't think that's the reason

Comment: "was it purely coincidental for the movie writer to write the lines to be used by Jennifer's ex-husband" — according to Wikipedia, Stan Chervin worked on the screenplay before Brad Pitt committed to the project in 2007. The line could have been written during that period.

Comment: @Vishwa - Is it really that ubiquitous?  The only two times I've ever heard it were these two programs.  And, add to the fact that they were romantically involved for several years.  Likely it was a saying that they used with each other, and each of them still use to this day.  Now, actors are not slaves to the screenplay.  They are allowed to ad lib to a degree.  I find it highly more likely that each of these occurrences were extemporaneous ad libs.

Comment: My completely unsourced and unfounded theory is that a) it was written for the *Friends* episode by the teleplay writer(s). b) Something about it struck Aniston as she rehearsed and spoke the line so she continued to use it as appropriate in real life. c) Pitt picked it up from her during their tabloid dalliance. d) Pitt ad-libbed it on the set of *Moneyball* and the director decided to keep it.